# How to reshape numpy arrays inside a list and append/extend results?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of arrays with each array shape (2, 2). I want to "divide" them by rows so that each row is added to a new list of (1, 2).

Example:

```
X = np.random.rand(2, 2)
Y = np.random.rand(2, 2)
li = [X, Y]
li
[array([[0.06959048, 0.14011019],
        [0.8171005 , 0.31335564]]),
 array([[0.94952885, 0.15987638],
        [0.8033848 , 0.56760287]])]
```

I want this result:

```
new_li
[array([0.06959048, 0.14011019]),
 array([0.8171005 , 0.31335564]),
 array([0.94952885, 0.15987638]),
 array([0.8033848 , 0.56760287])]
```

I know that extend for each variables will do the desired result, e.g.:

```
li.extend(X)
li.extend(Y)
```

But I have a pre-existing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
new_li = []
new_li.extend(j for i in li for j in i)
```

This will split each row and then extend all.